# How to convert Python code to executable code and have it run in systems where python is not installed?

Tags: python, html, pandas, exe

I have a python script that uses pandas to merge three different excel sheets and provides an output to a new excel sheet and save it in the directory. I want to share this code to everyone else to use it without having python installed in their systems. I did find lots of comments on using pyinstaller etc. but this is not working and the .exe file does not give the required output.

I am also open to suggestions to have any easy alternative solution other than .exe file that lets any user use my python code without having python in their systems.

error when used cx_Freeze

```
(base) Vikrams-MacBook-Pro:~ vikram$ cd Documents/Autoquery
(base) Vikrams-MacBook-Pro:Autoquery vikram$ python tool.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tool.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cx_Freeze
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'
(base) Vikrams-MacBook-Pro:Autoquery vikram$
```

error when used pyinstaller - I do get the .exe file, however it has the following error:

```
Last login: Tue May 12 20:13:45 on ttys000
/Users/vikram/Documents/Autoquery/dist/autoqueries ; exit;

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) Vikrams-MacBook-Pro:~ vikram$ /Users/vikram/Documents/Autoquery/dist/autoqueries ; exit;
[8084] Error loading Python lib '/var/folders/0v/1tnqz94x2b5_fb_c5fd43fk40000gn/T/_MEIWuQco2/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/var/folders/0v/1tnqz94x2b5_fb_c5fd43fk40000gn/T/_MEIWuQco2/Python, 10): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /var/folders/0v/1tnqz94x2b5_fb_c5fd43fk40000gn/T/_MEIWuQco2/Python: code signature invalid for '/var/folders/0v/1tnqz94x2b5_fb_c5fd43fk40000gn/T/_MEIWuQco2/Python'

logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Show us your code and explain what do yo mean by "not giving the required output". Also you can't go wrong with PyInstaller.

Comment: I have included my code for your review. When I try to make this code executable, I get an error.

Comment: Please put your complete error log.

Comment: I have added the error messages that I get when used pyinstaller and cx_Freeze

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you: https://www.py2exe.org/

It packages your code (and all its dependencies) into a .exe file that can be executed on a computer that has no python installed. But beware, depending on your dependencies the resulting executable can be quite large.

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you help me with add a GUI to my pandas script? for the above pandas script I would like a GUI where I need three filedialog widgets to browse and choose 3 excel files and then my pandas script runs and produces an excel output which i want to save in a directory i choose.

Comment: You should ask a seperate question for this issue as it is not related to this question. Also, I am not experienced with GUI programming in python, but Tkinter seems to be a popular choice.